# Why does this tkinter login window not work?

Tags: python, tkinter

Im learning tkinter and ran into a problem while making a login window. Im not sure if i even made it the right or most effective ay but id appreciate some help.

Ive tried a few different ways to do this but havnt found anything yet.

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import messagebox

def userpass():

    u = username.get
    p = password.get()

    if (p == '123' and u == 'test'):
        messagebox.showinfo("Login", "Correct")

    else:
        messagebox.showinfo("Login", "incorrect")

app = Tk()   
password = StringVar()
username = StringVar()
userlabel = Label(app, text = 'username:').grid(row = 1, column = 0)
passlabel = Label(app, text = 'password:').grid(row = 2, column = 0)
userEntry = Entry(app, textvariable = username,).grid(row = 1,
column = 1)
    passEntry = Entry(app, textvariable = password, show = '*').grid(row = 2, column = 1)
    login = Button(app, text = 'login',command = userpass).grid(row = 3, column = 1)

app.mainloop()
```

When i run the program and enter the correct login details, the wrong messagebox pops up.

Comment: you forget `()` after `u = username.get`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a bug in `userpass` function. `username.get` is a function, which on call returns the current value of the corresponding `Entry` text box. thus, it should be called as

```
u = username.get()
```

and, this should work.

Comment: @albertjjj Great! Please accept the answer. Thanks!

Comment: @albertjjj No, please don't accept the answer. Typo questions shouldn't be answered, they should be closed. The answer prevents the [roomba](https://stackoverflow.com/help/roomba) from auto-deleting the question once it's closed.